# Getting value of number input using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to make an easy website (as I've just started learning javascript) that would contain just a list of two quadratic equations and three number inputs to each equation. In these three inputs (a, b, and c) the user should write the coefficients of the quadratic equation, (for example: `x^2+x-2=0` -> a: 1, b: 1, c: -2).

This is how my HTML looks like:

```js
document.getElementById("button").onclick = function() {
  resultScore()
};

function resultScore() {
  var score = 0;
  if (document.getElementByName('coef1a').value = 1) {
    score += 1;
  }
  if (document.getElementByName('coef1b').value = 1) {
    score += 1;
  }
  if (document.getElementByName('coef1c').value = -2) {
    score += 1;
  }
  if (document.getElementByName('coef2a').value = 1 / 2) {
    score += 1;
  }
  if (document.getElementByName('coef2b').value = 4) {
    score += 1;
  }
  if (document.getElementByName('coef2c').value = -2) {
    score += 1;
  }

  alert(score);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>`x^2+x-2=0`</li>
  a: <input type="number" name="coef1a" min="-10" max="10"> b: <input type="number" name="coef1b" min="-10" max="10"> c: <input type="number" name="coef1c" min="-10" max="10"><br><br><br>
  <li>`1/2x^2+4x-2=0`</li>
  a: <input type="number" name="coef2a" min="-10" max="10"> b: <input type="number" name="coef2b" min="-10" max="10"> c: <input type="number" name="coef2c" min="-10" max="10"><br><br><br>
</ul>

<button type="button" id="button" onclick="alertFunction()">Submit</button>
```

For every correct answer, the user should get score +1 (so a user can get 6 points in total).

After you click the "submit" button the website should alert the number of points. The problem is that it doesn't alert anything.

Comment: You have assignments not comparisons `document.getElementByName('coef1b').value == 1` notice double equal sign.

Comment: Also, it's `getElementsByName` with a plural `Elements`. You should see the error in the snippet and in your browser. While debugging, to check errors, press F12  and check the console.

Comment: Fixed: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/5s8dxhvL/ (you also had `alertFunction()` as onclick, but the function is named `resultScore`)

Comment: You are assigning the values in `resultScore()`

Answer (score 0):

Your mistakes was:

1-You have to write `document.getElementsByName('...')[0] == x` instead of `document.getElementByName('...') = x`

2- You have to remove the following code:

```
document.getElementById("button").onclick = function() {
  resultScore()
};
```

3- You have to change `onclick` of button to `resultScore()`

Change your JS code to the following code:

```
function resultScore() {
  var score = 0;
  if (document.getElementsByName('coef1a')[0].value == 1) {
    score += 1;
  }
  if (document.getElementsByName('coef1b')[0].value == 1) {
    score += 1;
  }
  if (document.getElementsByName('coef1c')[0].value == -2) {
    score += 1;
  }
  if (document.getElementsByName('coef2a')[0].value == 1 / 2) {
    score += 1;
  }
  if (document.getElementsByName('coef2b')[0].value == 4) {
    score += 1;
  }
  if (document.getElementsByName('coef2c')[0].value == -2) {
    score += 1;
  }

  alert(score);
}
```

And your HTML code to:

```
<ul>
  <li>`x^2+x-2=0`</li>
  a: <input type="number" name="coef1a" min="-10" max="10"> b: <input type="number" name="coef1b" min="-10" max="10"> c: <input type="number" name="coef1c" min="-10" max="10"><br><br><br>
  <li>`1/2x^2+4x-2=0`</li>
  a: <input type="number" name="coef2a" min="-10" max="10"> b: <input type="number" name="coef2b" min="-10" max="10"> c: <input type="number" name="coef2c" min="-10" max="10"><br><br><br>
</ul>
<button type="button" id="button" onclick="resultScore()">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain your values in a much simpler way by wrapping your elements in a form and then building an object to hold all of your input values like so:

```js
let form = document.getElementById("form");
form.onsubmit = ev => {
  // prevent form submit
  ev.preventDefault();
  // Build object to hold form input values 
  let formData = Object.values(form).reduce((obj, field) => {
    obj[field.name] = field.value;
    return obj;
  }, {});
  console.log(formData);
  // Do score result operations
  resultScore(formData);
};

resultScore = formData => {
  var score = 0;
  // Double equal sign for the if conditions below
  if (formData.coef1a == 1) {
    score += 1;
  }
  if (formData.coef1b == 1) {
    score += 1;
  }
  if (formData.coef1c == -2) {
    score += 1;
  }
  if (formData.coef2a == 1 / 2) {
    score += 1;
  }
  if (formData.coef2b == 4) {
    score += 1;
  }
  if (formData.coef2c == -2) {
    score += 1;
  }

  alert(score);
}
```

```html
<form id='form'>
  <ul>
    <li>`x^2+x-2=0`</li>
    a: <input type="number" name="coef1a" min="-10" max="10"> b: <input type="number" name="coef1b" min="-10" max="10"> c: <input type="number" name="coef1c" min="-10" max="10"><br><br><br>
    <li>`1/2x^2+4x-2=0`</li>
    a: <input type="number" name="coef2a" min="-10" max="10"> b: <input type="number" name="coef2b" min="-10" max="10"> c: <input type="number" name="coef2c" min="-10" max="10"><br><br><br>
  </ul>
  <button type="submit" id="button">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiple Errors:

1. `document.getElementsByName` has to be **plural** (not `document.getElementByName`)
2. `document.getElementsByName` returns a NodeList (think of it as an array) so you have to **select the first index**
3. In an if statement, you must use `==` and not `=` (`==` is meant to **compare** whereas `=` is meant to **assign** values to a variable)

```js
document.getElementById("button").onclick = function() {
  resultScore()
};

function resultScore() {
  var score = 0;
  if (document.getElementsByName('coef1a')[0].value == 1) {
    score += 1;
  }
  if (document.getElementsByName('coef1b')[0].value == 1) {
    score += 1;
  }
  if (document.getElementsByName('coef1c')[0].value == -2) {
    score += 1;
  }
  if (document.getElementsByName('coef2a')[0].value == 1 / 2) {
    score += 1;
  }
  if (document.getElementsByName('coef2b')[0].value == 4) {
    score += 1;
  }
  if (document.getElementsByName('coef2c')[0].value == -2) {
    score += 1;
  }

  alert(score);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>`x^2+x-2=0`</li>
  a: <input type="number" name="coef1a" min="-10" max="10"> b: <input type="number" name="coef1b" min="-10" max="10"> c: <input type="number" name="coef1c" min="-10" max="10"><br><br><br>
  <li>`1/2x^2+4x-2=0`</li>
  a: <input type="number" name="coef2a" min="-10" max="10"> b: <input type="number" name="coef2b" min="-10" max="10"> c: <input type="number" name="coef2c" min="-10" max="10"><br><br><br>
</ul>

<button type="button" id="button">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `+document.querySelector('input[name="coef1a"]').value === 1` for it to work.

Notice the `+`, which is here to convert the value to a number, also, you have to use `===` to do a comparison, not `=` which is the assignment operator.

Also, if you want to query your inputs by name, use [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) which takes an arbitrary selector as argument, such as `input[name="X"]`.

```js
document.getElementById("button").onclick = function() {
  resultScore()
};

function resultScore() {
  var score = 0;
  if (+document.querySelector('input[name="coef1a"]').value === 1) {
    score += 1;
  }
  if (+document.querySelector('input[name="coef1b"]').value === 1) {
    score += 1;
  }
  if (+document.querySelector('input[name="coef1c"]').value === -2) {
    score += 1;
  }
  if (+document.querySelector('input[name="coef2a"]').value === 1 / 2) {
    score += 1;
  }
  if (+document.querySelector('input[name="coef2b"]').value === 4) {
    score += 1;
  }
  if (+document.querySelector('input[name="coef2c"]').value === -2) {
    score += 1;
  }

  alert(score);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>`x^2+x-2=0`</li>
  a: <input type="number" name="coef1a" min="-10" max="10"> b: <input type="number" name="coef1b" min="-10" max="10"> c: <input type="number" name="coef1c" min="-10" max="10"><br><br><br>
  <li>`1/2x^2+4x-2=0`</li>
  a: <input type="number" name="coef2a" min="-10" max="10"> b: <input type="number" name="coef2b" min="-10" max="10"> c: <input type="number" name="coef2c" min="-10" max="10"><br><br><br>
</ul>

<button type="button" id="button" onclick="alertFunction()">Submit</button>
```